Is it possible for a quadratic function to not have $y$-intercept?
I know quadratic functions may have up to two $x$-intercepts, but can they have no $y$-intercepts?
Edit: I mean quadratic functions which output parabolas (i.e. $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ where $a\neq0$). So those that open either upward or downward. Sorry for the vagueness.

Assuming you mean a quadratic function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ then... $x=0$ is always in the domain of the function.  What does $x=0$ have to do with a $y$-intercept?  If you do not mean a quadratic function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ then you need to be far more specific.

No, a function $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ will always have a $y$-intercept at $(0,c)$.  More general quadratic equations (like $x = y^2 + 3$) may not have a $y$-intercept, though.

I suppose if you want to be pedantic, we could also... say... label the first axis as $t$ and the second axis as $z$... and graph this in the $t$-$z$ plane rather than the $x$-$y$ plane...  In that case we don't have a "y-intercept"... we have a "z-intercept"... or we could label the first axis as candy and the second axis as unicorns... but I doubt this is what you mean to ask about.

It depends what you mean by a quadratic function. If you extend to the points in the $xy-$plane which satisfy a quadratic equation in $x$ and $y$ you get a conic section.

@JairTaylor I don't think OP wants f(y). In that case, the answer is simply no, I guess.

In order for a quadratic function $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ to not have a $y$-intercept, it's necessary that $f(0)$ must not exist (DNE). Seeing that $f(0)=a(0)^2+b(0)+c=c$, it follows that $f(0)$ necessarily must exist. Therefore, it is not possible for a quadratic function to lack $\mathbf{y}$-intercept unless explicitly stated otherwise in its construction.
So it seems that your question boils down to one with regards toward understanding the definition of (i) functions and (ii) $y$-intercepts. I have provided links (to Khan Academy) which provide a concrete definitions as well additional explanation for each concept. If you need any further help, please comment on this response post. (Math SE is a very intimidating environment for these kinds of question...so I hope I can be of some use.)
